# Information If Upvote On Answer Is From OP

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, upvotes

I'd like to propose that if an answer is posted and then upvoted by the original poster (instead of accepting the answer), then the information on who upvoted be provided either only to the user who answered, or everyone. This brings some closure in cases where the OP doesn't know about accepting answers or feels like the answer helped but still working on it.

Comment: I really like the concept of *voting is anonymous* and don't fancy to complicate that feature with *except in these cases*. The benefit of this feature is unclear to me.

Comment: I don't see any value in this proposal. For what purpose? What closure?

Comment: What about a downvote from the OP? and if the OP don't want to upvote? will you *spam* him with comments like : *don't forget to upvote* ?

Comment: The benefit is that when posting an answer, you are proposing a solution and getting validation that your solution was accepted reinforces your thoughts on the issue. If a solution is not accepted/upvoted that leaves some speculation about the relevance of the answer. In the world of Computer Science, everything changes so what was once a valid and relevant answer might not be anymore. Knowing the OP has upvoted confirms your solution is still up to date and relevant.

I'm not suggesting anything about downvotes, and spamming is still undesirable just as it is asking OP to accept the answer.

Comment: @rene I like the anonymity as well but when you expose yourself asking a question, you should be fine with exposing yourself if you upvote the answer. I am not talking about the identity of ALL upvoters, only if it's from the OP.

Comment: @PYB "_Knowing the OP has upvoted confirms your solution is still up to date and relevant._" - The answer might be relevant to the OP, but often the OP is not the best person do judge on the correctness of a answer. Other users might be more experienced in the topic, making their votes more valuable than the one given by OP.

Comment: @ModusTollens I agree for some higher-level concept questions, but when it comes to debugging, only the OP can provide feedback as if the answer fixed the issue.

Comment: If only OP can provide feedback if the answer solved issue usually suggests few things. First, that question does not have proper minimal reproducible example and next, that it is very unlikely that such Q/A pair will help future visitors and as such probably should not have been answered in the first place.

Comment: Yes, sometimes somewhat unclear question can be answered by wild guessing and if guessing is correct question can be improved and made useful for broader audience. It is far easier to ask OP for feedback in comment if you think it really matters so much in particular case.

Comment: @PYB I've seen programming beginners accept quick fixes from other beginners because they seemed to fix their problem when in reality they didn't, or introduced new potential errors - I'd be  very careful to associate acceptance marks and upvotes from OP with "good and correct answer". (For that reason, I wish we would get rid of the acceptance mark, or at least don't display accepted answers at the top automatically.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and better in case of privacy) to just show a popup for new OPs when they upvote saying they could also consider accepting the answer when it solves their issue?

Comment: @Tom Keep in mind that _very_ new OPs can't upvote: they need at least 15 reputation points

Comment: @ModusTollens Since this whole Q&A is about upvoting OPs and how to react on these upvote, that isn't something we need to bother right now.

Comment: @Tom Just thought I'd mention that for users who stumble upon this thread and don't know.

Answer (score 4):

Votes are meant to be anonymous; users won't know who upvoted [including the OP] their answer. Checkmarks [accepted answers] are always done by the OP; you already know if the OP positively reviewed your answer if the OP accepted that answer.